# XPATH Python expression

Tags: python, xml, xpath, python-3.x, libxml2

I am new to XPATH. I am using Python and the libxml module to try and only get the nodes such as `<TITLE>` and `<TARGET>` but only between certain dates. For example, when calling `python program.py 01/04/12 01/20/12` I would only like to have the nodes between these two dates and I can not figure out a good way of going about this. Perhaps there is an XPATH expression that I could use. Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE SCAN_LIST_OUTPUT SYSTEM "https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/scan/scan_list_output.dtd">
<SCAN_LIST_OUTPUT>
<RESPONSE>
<DATETIME>2012-02-13T14:54:21Z</DATETIME>
<SCAN_LIST>
  <SCAN>
    <REF>scan/121212112.61291</REF>
    <TYPE>Scheduled</TYPE>
    <TITLE><![CDATA[Company A 5/19/2012]]></TITLE>
    <USER_LOGIN>username</USER_LOGIN>
    <LAUNCH_DATETIME>2012-05-20T04:10:05Z</LAUNCH_DATETIME>
    <STATUS>
      <STATE>Finished</STATE>
    </STATUS>
    <TARGET><![CDATA[10.1.1.1, 10.1.1.1, 10.1.1.1, 10.1.1.1...]]></TARGET>
  </SCAN>
  <SCAN>
    <REF>scan/12121212.1212</REF>
    <TYPE>Scheduled</TYPE>
    <TITLE><![CDATA[Company B 5/19/2012]]></TITLE>
    <USER_LOGIN>username</USER_LOGIN>
    <LAUNCH_DATETIME>2012-05-19T04:10:06Z</LAUNCH_DATETIME>
    <STATUS>
      <STATE>Finished</STATE>
    </STATUS>
    <TARGET><![CDATA[10.2.2.2, 10.2.3.3, 10.2.14.5, 10.1.2...]]></TARGET>
  </SCAN>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Mark Pilgrim's *Dive Into Python 3*, Chapter 6. XML, section [12.6. Going Further With lxml](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/xml.html#xml-lxml).